# OpenURI::HTTPError Exception: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, user-agent, open-uri

Unable to open URL "http://www.diretaimoveisbh.com.br//Resultado.asp?nTransacao=V&vid_tipoimovel=&vId_bairro=&pagina=11" with open-uri, It keeps throwing error "OpenURI::HTTPError Exception: 500 Internal Server Error", I searched everywhere but didnt got any solution.
Please help If anyone here know how to resolve that issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have access to the server, check the logs. 500 means server side error and there isn't much the client can do about it.

Comment: Accessing that URL in browser works fine, but the same URL throws 500 Internal Server Error while try to open with Open-URI, after a bit reasearch I got to know there might be something related to Uer-agent, however I didnt got it working in any way.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a 500 back from the server, something is really broken somewhere, probably on the server. Maybe the URL is broken too.

Expect issues retrieving the data you want unless you receive a 200 back from the server. 200 code means everything you expect should be there, 4xx or 5xx code is something completely different, see for more info.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

In the meantime, you may try/catch the exception, but keep in mind, its most likely not going to contain anything (except maybe error information) in the payload until its returning a 200.